# How can I remove all font tags that have nothing but whitespace in them, using Perl?

Tags: html, regex, perl

I'm trying to do a match in Perl, using the following regex:

```
s/<font(.*?)>[\t\f ]*<\/font>//gi;
```

What I want it to do is to remove all font tags that don't have anything inside.

Unfortunately, it doesn't stop after `<font` at the first `>` it will go until the `>` from before `</font>`.

Any pointers on what is wrong with the regex?

```
my $text1 = '<font color="#008080"><span style="background: #ffffff"></span></font>';
my $text2 = '<font color="#008080">    s</font>';
my $text2 = '<font></font>';
$text1 =~ s/<font(.*?)>[\t\f ]*<\/font>//gi;
$text2 =~ s/<font(.*?)>[\t\f ]*<\/font>//gi;
$text3 =~ s/<font(.*?)>[\t\f ]*<\/font>//gi;
print "$text1\n$text2\n$text3\n";
```

will print

```
 
<font>s</font>
```

Comment: Any reason for using regex to parse HTML? There are decent HTML parsers for Pearl that you might use. Quote from Jamie Zawinski: `Some people, when confronted with a problem, think 'I know, I'll use regular expressions.' Now they have two problems.`.

Comment: [Friends don't let friends parse HTML with regular expressions.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: Well, it's not actually html code, it's wiki code which I want to clean up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Obligatory warning: [You shouldn't use regex to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-rege).

---

While `.*?` is lazy, it does not mean it will avoid a match to be succeed. In $text1,

```
<font color="#008080"><span style="background: #ffffff"></span></font>
```

it is possible to match `<font(.*?)>[\t\f ]*<\/font>` by having `.*?` match the `" color="#008080"><span style="background: #ffffff"></span"`. This is the *shortest match* that will cause the match to *succeed*.

If you want to stop at the first `>`, use

```
s|<font[^>]*>\s*</font>||gi
#      ^^^^
```

This assumes a `>` won't appear inside a `<font>` tag. (Example violation: `<font onclick="return 1>2"></font>`.)

Answer (score 11):

If you are using XHTML, then this is pretty easy with [XML::Twig](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Twig):

```
use XML::Twig;

my $string = <<"HTML";
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<html>
<font color="#008080"><span style="background: #ffffff"></span></font>
<font color="#008080">    s</font>
<font></font>
</html>
HTML

use XML::Twig;
my $twig = XML::Twig->new( 
    pretty_print => 'nice',
    twig_handlers => {
        span => \&delete_empty,
        font => \&delete_empty,
        },
    );
$twig->parse( $string );

$twig->print;

sub delete_empty {
    my( $twig, $element ) = @_;

    $element->delete unless $element->text =~ /\S/;
    }
```

You can also use [HTML::Tree](http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTML-Tree), but I don't have time to write an example right now (and now that I do, [Greg Bacon has already done it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3741496/how-can-i-remove-all-font-tags-that-have-nothing-but-whitespace-in-them-using-pe/3741934#3741934)). I don't show you how to do this particular task in my [Process HTML with a Perl Module](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1581075) article for InformIT, but most of the pieces are there.

Answer (score 4):

The code below uses the [HTML::TreeBuilder](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML::TreeBuilder) module, which is an appropriate tool for parsing HTML. Regular expressions are not.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

use HTML::TreeBuilder;
```

The test cases from your question:

```
my @cases = (
  '<font color="#008080"><span style="background: #ffffff"></span></font>',
  '<font color="#008080">    s</font>',
  '<font></font>',
);
```

We'll use `is_empty` as a predicate to the [`look_down`](http://search.cpan.org/~petek/HTML-Tree-3.23/lib/HTML/Element.pm#$h-%3Elook_down%28_...criteria..._%29) method of [HTML::Element](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML::Element) to find `<font>` elements with no interesting content.

```
sub is_empty {
  my($font) = @_;

  my $is_interesting = sub {
    for ($_[0]->content_list) {
      return 1 if !ref($_) && /\S/;
    }
  };

  !$font->look_down($is_interesting);
}
```

Finally the main loop. For each fragment, we create a new `HTML::TreeBuilder` instance, remove empty `<font>` elements, and trim the first-level text content of those that remain.

```
foreach my $html (@cases) {
  my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_content($html);
  $_->detach for $tree->guts->look_down(_tag => "font", \&is_empty);

  my $result = "";
  if ($tree->guts) {
    foreach my $font ($tree->guts->look_down(_tag => "font")) {
      $font->attr($_,undef) for $font->all_external_attr_names;
      foreach my $text ($font->content_refs_list) {
        next if ref $$text;
        $$text =~ s/^\s+//;
        $$text =~ s/\s+$//;
      }
    }

    ($result = $tree->guts->as_HTML) =~ s/\s+$//;
  }

  print "$result\n";
}
```

Output:

```
    
<font>s</font>
```

Making two passes is sloppy. The code could be improved:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

use HTML::TreeBuilder;

my @cases = (
  '<font color="#008080"><span style="background: #ffffff"></span></font>',
  '<font color="#008080">    s</font>',
  '<font></font>',
);

foreach my $fragment (@cases) {
  my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_content($fragment);
  foreach my $font ($tree->guts->look_down(_tag => "font")) {
    $font->detach, next
      unless $font->look_down(sub { grep !ref && /\S/ => $_[0]->content_list });

    $font->attr($_,undef) for $font->all_external_attr_names;
    foreach my $text ($font->content_refs_list) {
      next if ref $$text;
      $$text =~ s/^\s+//;
      $$text =~ s/\s+$//;
    }
  }

  (my $cleaned = $tree->guts ? $tree->guts->as_HTML : "") =~ s/\s+$//;
  print $cleaned, "\n";
}
```

Comment: I need to know: why do you do $font->detach?

Comment: @cristi The code uses it to delete empty `font` elements. According to the [documentation for `HTML::Element`](http://search.cpan.org/~jfearn/HTML-Tree-4.0/lib/HTML/Element.pm), `$h->detach()` “unlinks `$h` from its parent, by setting its ‘parent’ attribute to `undef`, and by removing it from the content list of its parent (if it had one).”

Comment: Thank you. An other question: why !ref in grep? this will also remove

Comment: Thank you. An other question: why !ref in grep? this will also remove <font><IMG SRC="asdf"> </font>

Comment: @cristi Maybe I misunderstood what you want. Should `$text1` (which has an empty `span`) from your original example remain or be deleted?

Answer (score 2):

I am really fond of [HTML::TokeParser::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/HTML::TokeParser::Simple). So, for variety, here is another way:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;
use HTML::TokeParser::Simple;

my $parser = HTML::TokeParser::Simple->new( \*DATA );

while ( my $stag = $parser->get_token ) {
    if ( $stag->is_start_tag( qr/font|span/ ) ) {
        my $closer = '/' . $stag->get_tag;
        my $text   = $parser->get_text( $closer );
        my $etag   = $parser->get_tag( $closer );

        if ( $text =~ /\S/ ) {
            $text =~ s/^\s+//;
            $text =~ s/\s+\z//;
            print $stag->as_is, $text, $etag->as_is;
        }
    }
    else {
        print $stag->as_is;
    }
}


__DATA__
<h1>Test heading</h1>
<p>Here is some <b>sample</b> <em>text</em>: <span>one</span>
<font color="#008080"><span style="background: #ffffff"></span></font>
<font color="#008080">    s</font>
<font></font></p>

<h2>A subtitle</h2>
<p><q>this is a test</q>: ya ba da ba doo!</p>
</body>
```

Output:

```
<h1>Test heading</h1>
<p>Here is some <b>sample</b> <em>text</em>: <span>one</span>

<font color="#008080">s</font>
</p>

<h2>A subtitle</h2>
<p><q>this is a test</q>: ya ba da ba doo!</p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s/<font[^>]*>\s*<\/font>//gi;
```

The non-greedy `.*?` tries to consume a minimal number of characters, but it will take as many as necessary to achieve an overall match.  If you replace it with `[^>]*`, the `>` has to match the very *next* `>`, or the match attempt fails.

Be aware that it's legal for `>` to appear in attribute values, so this solution isn't 100% guaranteed.  Fortunately, the people who know about that little loophole are also sensible enough not to use it; I've never seen an angle bracket in an attribute value in the wild.